# Define server function for mongo based on pure javascript function

Tags: javascript, mongodb

Suppose I have a pure javascript file that has several function definitions. It does not contain anything mongo-specific - these functions parse and evaluate a query on a document. I would like to use these functions for server queries (e.g. db.collection.find(...) or map-reduce). How may I do this so that the server functions can essentially invoke what's in the pure javascript file?

Example: In foobar.js -

```
function foo(query, doc) {
    // some predicate, for now lets simulate by evaluating a boolean field called 'available'
    return doc.available;
}
```

According to https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/store-javascript-function-on-server/
I would have to do this:

```
db.system.js.save(
   {
     _id : "bar" ,
     value : function (query, doc){
         return doc.available;
     }
   }
);
```

Then invoke db.loadServerScripts();
Running the following gives me the desired results:

```
db.myCollection.find(function() { return bar("some query", this) ;})
```

However I'd like to avoid inlining the functions in this db.system.js.save call. These functions belong to a library that I do not maintain. If there are any changes to the javascript library, I would have to manually convert them to db.system.js.save calls.

I would like to run something like this in mongo shell:

```
load("foobar.js")
db.system.js.save(
   {
     _id : "baz" ,
     value : function (query, doc){
         return foo(query, doc);
     }
   }
);
```

Then:

```
db.myCollection.find(function() { return baz("some query", this); })
```

But I get a "ReferenceError: foo is not defined" in my queries that invoke baz. Function "foo" is clearly not in scope. Suggestions or alternatives?

**Disclaimer: I understand that using native operations are preferred, in addition to moving complexity out of the javascript into my application. However I am not at the point where I have the resources to essentially fork the logic from  javascript to application logic that decomposes to native ops**